# Alignment issue in Request topic close button

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

In the Documentation Beta for any topic, when we are click on the **Request Topic** button, in the pop over the close button is not aligned properly.

This issue occurs in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Example: [Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/topics) -> Click **Request Topic** button (it is in the right hand side top).

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Request topic - close button]

Comment: In `rev 2017.6.6.26150` still the issue is exist.

Comment: In `rev 2017.6.8.26174` it was fixed